# Gem5 simulator installing Error

Tags: virtualbox, compiling

I got the below errors after compiling Gem5 simulator
(downloaded from Gem5.org) on ubuntu 20.04 using VirtualBox.

what are these errors and how can I fix them, please?

the command is: build/X86/gem5.opt configs/learning_gem5/part1/simple.py

```
collect2: fatal error: ld terminated with signal 9 [Killed]
compilation terminated.
scons: *** [build/X86/gem5.opt] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
*** Summary of Warnings ***
Warning: Deprecated namespaces are not supported by this compiler.
         Please make sure to check the mailing list for deprecation
         announcements.
```

Comment: What is Gem5? From where it was downloaded? Please provide as much details as you can to make your question reproducible.

Comment: Thank you... Gem5 is a simulator I am planning to use for my MSC project / computer Engineering. Downloaded from Gem5.org site.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to build a gem5 example ? ......... But the command causing your errors is missing. Please add the command to your question → The *Edit* button https://askubuntu.com/posts/1389922/edit

Comment: Thank you ... i did so.

Answer (score 0):

The command looks fine. But the problem is the process is using too much RAM and the system has aborted it. Best way to rectify this is to restart the system or close the unnecessary applications running in the background and try to run again. This way you can free up some space on RAM.

Comment: Try to also increase the swap space, that also works!